# How to remove duplication in the retrieval results?

Tags: php, mysql

Please i need a help am beginner in php and my sql, i want to retrieve all students names who registered in each level(1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4) this is my code.

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table border="1" align="center" class="tftable">
    <?php
     $lvlid = $_GET['id'];
     $sql2 = "select * from `course` where acadlevel='$lvlid' ";
     $res2= mysql_query($sql2,$con_mark_entry);
     while($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($res2))
     {?>
     <?php } ?>
  <tr>
      <th id="h7">Serial NO.</th>
      <th id="h7">Student NO.</th>
      <th id="h7">Student Name</th>
        </tr>
  <?php
       $s=1;
       $sql ="SELECT student.stud_id,student.stud_name, course.title, enrollment.grade FROM student, course, enrollment WHERE course.acadlevel ='".$_GET['id'] ."' AND course.code = enrollment.code AND student.stud_id = enrollment.stud_id";
        $res= mysql_query($sql,$con_mark_entry);
        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
        ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $s?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $row1[0]?></td>
      <td id="name"><a href="report6.php?id=<?php echo $row1[1]?>"> <?php echo $row1[1]?> </td>
    </tr>
     <?php
    $s++;
    }

?>
  </table>
```

My Problem is for example if the student registered in three course at level 1 ,he would appear three times, i want to remove this duplication. HOW?

The result as follow:

serial no student no student name
      1         101       adam nagdy
      2         101       adam nagdy
      3         101       adam nagdy
      4         102       shima najm

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using SELECT DISTINCT on the student query?

Comment: Really helps to see the data.

Comment: please if you can help me to update the code don't hesitate

Comment: actually i used SELECT DISTINCT but it give me the same result

Comment: Mr/Andrew do you want to see my result or my database

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` keyword. It removes duplicate result rows.

Search for "distinct" in this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

```
SELECT DISTINCT std.stud_id,std.stud_name, enr.grade -- , crs.title
FROM student std
LEFT OUTER JOIN enrollment enr ON std.stud_id = enr.stud_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN course crs ON crs.code = enr.code 
WHERE course.acadlevel ='YOUR_ID'
```

And use `JOIN` to join. ;) It is better than joining with `WHERE` (even if it works).

Comment: i used your code but it retrieve the same result :(

Comment: Show us your result, please.

Comment: Remove the `course.title` in the query. ;) As it seems you don't need it, it is okay. Or use GROUP_CONCAT...

Comment: And please, look at John Conde comment... It is so important not to use the old, unsecure mysql functions of php. Use MySQLi or PDO...

Comment: please i tried DISTINCT AND RETRIEVE THE SAME RESULT AND GROUPBY returned only one row

Comment: Remove crs.title to your query and tell us.

Comment: i deleted it and it still retrieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GROUP BY course.acadlevel` at the end of your query.

That should reduce the results to one row per academic level, instead of 3, if the student registered for 3 classes.

Also, as John Conde has commented, `mysql_` prefixed functions are deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. You should instead use [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).  And you should never use `$_GET[]`/`$_POST` or any other variables with user input in your MySQL queries without sanitizing them.